# Copy Transpose Paste Vertically Breaking on Blanks

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste

I am new to VBA and coding in general and I am being tasked with some coding that is proving difficult. I am trying to copy/transpose/paste values from a two-column PivotTable and I need it to paste vertically on another sheet and break on blanks. (see image) I need to copy each group in the PivotTable then transpose paste values vertically on a new worksheet. I believe I need to count populated rows (using an array?) until I get to a blank row then paste the group. I can picture what I need to do but all my coding attempts are way off. Except for the copy/paste, I have no clue how to code this. I cannot figure out how to capture each group of populated rows to be pasted.

```
' Copy a vertical range (on "FQNID_Sites" sheet) and paste to a horizontal range in column B (next blank row on "BH_FH" sheet)  

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet  
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FQNID_Sites")  

Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet  
Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BH_FH")  

Dim cellToPasteTo As Range  

' Need to loop through each group breaking on each siteNFID in column D (or break on blanks in column E?)  

Set rng = Range("$D$2:$E$" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 
For Each cell In rng 
    Set cellToPasteTo = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
    If cell.Value = "" And Not IsNull(copyStart) Then 
        copyEnd = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Address 
    ElseIf cell.Value = "" Then 
        copyStart = cell.Offset(0, -1).Address 
    End If  
    If Not IsNull(copyStart) And Not IsNull(copyEnd) Then 
        sourceSheet.Range(copyStart & ":" & copyEnd).Select 
        Selection.Copy 
        cellToPasteTo.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True 
    End If 
Next cell  

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I need it to break on each siteNFID/FQNID then paste values for each group vertically in column B on the BH_FH worksheet.

[Example of the input and expected output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf1eQ.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you not just restructure the PT?

Comment: I am new to this...what is the PT?

Comment: @Tom PT means Pivot Table

Comment: Cannot restructure the PivotTable because column E is not part of the PT

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. Tested on similar data structure. I used the code sheet name in the code `Sheet1'. Change as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub runTranspose()

    With Sheet1

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        'load range starts to transpose
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Len(.Cells(i, 5)) = 0 Then
                Dim startTranspose As Range
                If startTranspose Is Nothing Then
                    Set startTranspose = .Cells(i, 5)
                Else
                    Set startTranspose = Union(startTranspose, .Cells(i, 5))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In startTranspose
            transposeData c
        Next

    End With

End Sub

Sub transposeData(r As Range)

    With Sheet1

        Dim nextRow As Long
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim fullRange As Range
        Set fullRange = Range(r.Offset(1, -1), r.Offset(1).End(xlDown))

        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = fullRange.Value

        .Cells(nextRow,7).Value = r.offset(-1).Value 'to add label
        .Cells(nextRow, 8).Resize(2, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this!!!  I pasted your solution into my module and ran it and it outputted the entire columns D and E into column G, it did not break on siteNFID (or blanks in column E).  There are 10,800 input rows if that matters.  Also, in your example, I need A, B, and C output as well.

Comment: @tom - I added piece of code to place NFID in column G. I forgot that. I can't say why its not breaking on blanks in column E, as I designed it, because it does so perfectly for me, as you can see. Maybe there is a difference in what is in your column E. If you run my sample data against the small sample I built, then compare what is different to your data, you'll find the answer. Or better yet, debug my code directly on your data to see what it's doing that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you again for looking at this!  The code works beautifully except that it is outputting the entire columns D and E to each output line.  It does output starting with the correct data, it just includes the rest of the column data.  Ex. The second line starts with the second group, the third with the third and so on.  The only difference in my data vs yours is there is a formula in the blank cells down column E.  Not sure if that would matter since it's still zero length.

Comment: that formula does make a differnce. you need to adjust `Set fullRange = ...` to find the next cell in column E that returns a blank in the formula from the start. Using `End(xlDown)` directly is causing it to go the very bottom of column E.

Comment: I confirmed that the formula is causing the entire column to be output, remove it in the blank rows and it almost works perfectly.  I sincerely appreciate your time and effort!  Could you please provide an example of the modification you describe above?  Also, siteNFID is still not being output--instead it is outputting PERMITstatus into column B.